# Is there a way to use ARRAYs in Entity Framework + PostgreSql

Tags: arrays, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

Is it possible to use arrays in Entity Framework with PostgreSql?

Suppose, for instance, we had the POCO class

```
        public class MyTable
        {
            [Key]
            [Column("gid")]
            public int Gid { get; set; }
            [Column("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Column("email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Column("somedata")]
            public int[] SomeData { get; set; }
        }
```

At this point Entity Framework simply does not create the column "somedata" and skips it. Is there a way to do this anyway? And by that I mean not having to use a separate table. Postgres arrays come in handy at times where you want to store a small or limited number of values into a single column.

Comment: Probably depends on the data provider. Devart dotConnect claim they do.

Comment: @GertArnold, can you point to where Devart say they do this? I work on Npgsql and AFAIK EF itself isn't very open to types outside the basic ones.

Comment: Maybe I've said too much. [Here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) they about their ADO.NET Provider: "It support a wide range of PostgreSQL-specific features, such as secure SSL connections, PostgreSQL notifications, PostgreSQL bulk data loading, GEOMETRY, PostgreSQL ARRAY types, and others."

Comment: Ah, OK. I would guess that means they support it at the ADO.NET layer, rather than in EntityFramework. The problem seems more to be with EF itself, and not with Npgsql's or dotConnect's implementation of it. But I haven't looked at this very deeply.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any support from EF for this, it was just not designed this way. Take a look at the following [code](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/master/Npgsql.EntityFramework/NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator.cs#L579).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's possible to do this if you use [Entity Framework Core](https://github.com/aspnet/entityframework/) with the [Npgsql EF Core provider](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html).

The code-first approach would be:

```
[Column("somedata", TypeName = "integer[]")]
public int[] SomeData { get; set; }
```