# NPGSQL date time array

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, npgsql

I'm attempting to use the `timestamp[]` field type in Postgres with NPGSQL, so that I can use the `DateTime[]` type in my Entity Framework models.

I've added this to my EF code first model.

```
[Column("HostUnavailableDates", TypeName = "timestamp[]")]
public DateTime[] HostUnavailableDates { get; set; }
```

I've created a migration and the database has updated successfully.

However I am getting this error when executing transactions with the model.

```
Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'HostApplication.HostUnavailableDates' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'DateTime[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186515/is-there-a-way-to-use-arrays-in-entity-framework-postgresql) which does not use any type of ignoring of the property. Is there something I need to do for the DateTime type in addition to what I'm currently doing?

Is `DateTime` in fact not supported at all in this case?

I'm using EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Entity Framework 6.x. If that's the case, then arrays simply aren't supported, you'll have to switch to Entity Framework Core.

Comment: I'm using EF Core.