# EF Core Postgres List<T>.Contains entity property

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm facing a problem with EF Core Postgres List Property which is stored as array integer, .Contains() method is not being translated properly.

Entity:

```
 public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<int> TestArray { get; set; }
    }
```

Ef query:

```
var result = await _dbContext.Test
            .Where(x => x.TestArray.Contains(1)) //1 can be variable
            .ToListAsync();
```

Postgresql query:

```
SELECT *
      FROM "Test"
      WHERE (TRUE = FALSE)
```

Changing property type from List to int[] works perfectly, but List has to many benefits.
Even postgres documentation saying Contains is supported https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html.
Is there any workaround for this?

**UPD:** TestArray is postgres array column integer[]

Comment: Your DB should contain 2 tables, one with the Test class, but another with the collection of ints.   What does your look like?

Comment: TestArray is not a table, is an postgres column array type integer[], your solution is not allowed in this case as seems like you need to specife array type (array, list)

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186515/is-there-a-way-to-use-arrays-in-entity-framework-postgresql suggests that [] is the correct way.  TBH, you are trying to do something provider specific, and EF is a generic solution.  I'm surprised it even half works.

Comment: This is even how postgres suggest it to be done, Add and Remove works perfectly but not Contains :(

Comment: "PostgreSQL has the unique feature..." - and we've shoehorned it into EF ;-D

Comment: It is really helpful to use the correct tag and say if you mean EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x... It is also helpful to say what database provider you are using.

Comment: Based on the SQL translation it seems like EF / your provider doesn't realize the `TestArray` property maps to a database column.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, EF collections should be declared as `ICollection<XXX>`, and all the examples used to initialise it with a HashSet. You shouldn't use `[]` as that is a fixed size array, and you won't be able to add new records to it.

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> TestArray { get; set; } = new HashSet<int>();
}
```

Comment: That really depends on the database provider. Npgsql EF provider documentation recommends `[]` or `List<T>` for the property mapped to a 1-D array column type.