# Does EF functionality work against PostgreSQL like it does against SQL Server?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does EF functionality work against PostgreSQL like it does against SQL Server? Are there any limitations when using Entity Framework with Postgres as opposed to using EF with SQL Server? Do all the same EF features work with Postgres like they do with SQL Server?

Comment: Do you know "all the features"?

Comment: If you mean "Does EF functionality work against PostgreSQL like it does against SQL Server?" then Yes, it pretty much does. However, as far as the Entity and related table data structures go, there will be certain considerations. For example, PostgreSQL can support GUID via UUID columns, but unlike SQL Server, it doesn't natively have UUID generation methods like NEWID or NEWSEQUENTIALID so EF cannot treat these as Identity columns. PostgreSQL is case sensitive by default, both in data and schema so this can require extra configuration in EF to keep it happy when working with existing schemas.

Comment: I use EF /w PostgreSQL as a very capable and inexpensive alternative to SQL Server ,however your data model & config does need to be designed a bit differently. You probably should not expect to "hot-swap" a DbContext and entities from SQL Server over to PostgreSQL if that is a consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your response @StevePy, I changed the title as the question you suggested is better than my original one.  You answered my question.

Comment: I know of one feature only PostgreSql supports: [array types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29186515/861716). Still, this is not the type of question that works well on Stack Overflow, because it's hard to tell unambiguously when it's answered sufficiently. For one, a very important feature is the quality of generated queries in combination with the database's query engine. I wouldn't know where to begin to scope out the differences. Yet, it can make a world of difference.